# Material UI Autocomplete with Google Maps - Disabling secondary chrome browser previous search options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, material-ui, autosuggest

I am using the material ui autocomplete component with the Google places API and it works great except for one thing. Google is adding previous searches **ON TOP** of the Google suggestions:

[image]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ixlj6zfr5uxuzg/Screenshot%202019-11-21%2010.28.28.png?dl=0

**Here is the relevant code:**

```
<form className={classes.container} noValidate autoComplete='no'>
        <input
          autoComplete='no'
          name='hidden'
          type='text'
          className={classes.hiddenInput}
        />
        <Autocomplete
          onChange={(event, value) => setHere(value.description)}
          getOptionLabel={option => option.description}
          filterOptions={x => x}
          options={options}
          autoComplete
          includeInputInList
          freeSolo
          disableOpenOnFocus
          clearOnEscape
          renderInput={params => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              id='here'
              name='here'
              label='Here'
              variant='outlined'
              margin='normal'
              className={classes.textField}
              fullWidth
              onChange={handleChange}
              autoComplete='off'
            />
          )}
```

I have tried everything I can think of to make this go away. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Additionally, I am NOT using the google.maps.places.Autocomplete endpoint which generates its own widget, but instead the google.maps.places.AutocompleteService() which simply provides a feed to a input that you specify. I used this code as guide for the component:

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/components/autocomplete/GoogleMaps.tsx

Comment: How are you initializing the places autocomplete? Please add the relevant code. Note that `google.maps.places.Autocomplete` renders an own widget.